# Codeigniter URL Issues

Tags: codeigniter, routes, permalinks

I have some problem with my url.

I had copied my website script to another website of mine, and changed the url.

original permalink : (A)

```
domain.tld/path1/path2/post_title.html
```

I had changed it to the (B)

```
domain.tld/path1/post-title.html<br/>
```

but the problem is. When i open B, there is error

404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

and i tried to open 
domain.tld/path1/path2/post-title.html working fine.

Please help me to solve this issues.

Below are my .htaccess 
http://prntscr.com/2928f1

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `base url` in the `config` file that is in `app/config/config.php` with the new site path like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'domain.tld/path1/path2/';
```

And make sure that you has using same db orelse you also need to change the `DB config` also.And dont put the new folder that includes `path2` in the old path `path1`.If iam not wrong you are putting the new one in the older path.create a new folder with `domain.tld/path2/`

Answer (score 0):

No worry any more about `base url`.

In your application/config/config.php, change `$config['base_url']=''` to

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [l,QSA]
```